# react-apollo is not connecting to my graphql local server

Tags: react-native, graphql, react-apollo

I've been trying to connect to my local GraphQL server using Apollo. Below is my attempt using `react-apollo2.0`. But I have also tried with `react-apollo1.4` with `createNetworkInterface`, but I am getting the same error.

```
import { graphql } from 'react-apollo';
import gql from 'graphql-tag';
import { AppRegistry } from 'react-native';
import { HttpLink } from 'apollo-link-http';
import { InMemoryCache } from 'apollo-cache-inmemory';
import { ApolloClient } from 'apollo-client';
import { ApolloProvider } from 'react-apollo';

const client = new ApolloClient({
  link: new HttpLink({ uri: 'http://localhost:8000/graphql' }),
  cache: new InMemoryCache()
});

function FooList({ data: { loading, posts } }) {
  if (loading) {
    return <Text>Loading</Text>;
  } else {
      return (
        <List>
          <ListItem>
            <Left>
                <Text>John Doe5</Text>
                <Text note>(buyer)</Text>
            </Left>
            <Right>
                <Text note>21 min ago</Text>
            </Right>
          </ListItem>
        </List>
      );
  }
}

export default graphql(gql`
  query allLeads {
    id
    name
  }
`)(FooList);

const App = () => (
  <ApolloProvider client={client}>
    <FooList/>
  </ApolloProvider>
);

export default App;
```

Error I'm getting:

[image]

My dependencies.

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@expo/vector-icons": "^6.2.0",
    "apollo-client-preset": "^1.0.4",
    "expo": "^22.0.2",
    "graphql": "^0.11.7",
    "graphql-tag": "^2.6.0",
    "native-base": "^2.3.3",
    "react": "16.0.0-beta.5",
    "react-apollo": "^2.0.4",
    "react-link": "^1.0.3",
    "react-native": "^0.49.5",
    "react-navigation": "^1.0.0-beta.21"
  }
```

According to the docs this is how you are supposed to set it up. My server isn't being hit and I can access the graph browser at http://localhost:8000/graphql just fine.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Is your server at the same project that your mobile project?

Comment: No. It's a Django server.

Comment: Try using your local ip adress like 192.168.1.4 instead of 'localhost'

Comment: @Dyo: Same error. Used my IP address which is `192.168.1.4`. Docs say to use `localhost` as well.

Comment: Do you see more info about the error in console ? Or try this :
`function FooList({ data: { error, loading, posts } }) {
  if (error) {
    return <Text>{error.message}</Text>; }`

Comment: @Dyo: It says `Network error: Network request failed`. There is a huge stacktrace, but none of if seems relevant.

Comment: You can try 10.0.2.2:8000 or 10.0.3.2:8000 but 192.168.1.4:8000 should work, what emulator are your using ?

Comment: @Dyo: Thank you man! `10.0.2.2:8000` works. Getting a 403 from my Django server now. You know why this ip works though? If you write something quick up as an answer I will be happy to accept and upvote.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [Android docs](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-networking.html) :

> Each instance of the emulator runs behind a virtual router/firewall
> service that isolates it from your development machine network
> interfaces and settings and from the internet. An emulated device
> can't see your development machine or other emulator instances on the
> network. Instead, it sees only that it is connected through Ethernet
> to a router/firewall.
>
> The virtual router for each instance manages the 10.0.2/24 network
> address space — all addresses managed by the router are in the form of
> 10.0.2.xx, where xx is a number. Addresses within this space are pre-allocated by the emulator/router as follows:
>
> 10.0.2.1  Router/gateway address
>
> **10.0.2.2    Special alias to your host loopback interface (i.e., 127.0.0.1 on your development machine)**
>
> 10.0.2.3  First DNS server
>
> 10.0.2.4 / 10.0.2.5 / 10.0.2.6    Optional second, third and fourth DNS server (if any)
>
> 10.0.2.15 The emulated device network/ethernet interface
>
> 127.0.0.1 The emulated device loopback interface

Note that this virtual router is used by AVD emulator only, it may be different for other emulators

Answer (score 0):

i think the error i not related to apollo , it seems that you are using export default twice in one file since it is not allowed